# file locked after downloading with FtpWebRequest

Tags: vb.net, ftp

I have code that downloads a file from a given location and then later opens it up for processing. I do this over FTP via the FtpWebRequest and FtpWebResponse objects, reading the response into a StreamReader, and then writing that stream into a file via a StreamWriter.

The problem that I'm having is that when I later load the file into a StreamReader, I get an exception saying that my file is in use by another process. Interestingly, this doesn't happen if cases where the file isn't there to download, though I also don't get an exception in that case.

Here is the relevant code portion:

```
Try
            Dim ftpResponse As FtpWebResponse = DirectCast(ftpRequest.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)
            stream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream()
            reader = New StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8)

            Dim destinationFile As String = _workingDirectory + _filename
            writer = New StreamWriter(destinationFile, False)
            writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd())

            result = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            EventLog.LogEvent("UpdateInventory", String.Format("Unable to download file: {0}. <br/ > {1}", downloadUri, ex.ToString()), BVSoftware.BVC5.Core.Metrics.EventLogSeverity.Error)
        Finally
            If stream IsNot Nothing Then
                stream.Close()
            End If

            If reader IsNot Nothing Then
                reader.Close()
            End If

            If writer IsNot Nothing Then
                writer.Close()
            End If
        End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling writer.flush before closing it. It writes any buffered data to the underlying stream.
Here is how I have implemented it (http://dot-net-talk.blogspot.in/2008/12/how-to-create-ftp-client-in-vbnet.html):

```
Public Function Download(ByVal sourceFilename As String, ByVal targetFI As FileInfo, Optional ByVal PermitOverwrite As Boolean = False) As Boolean
    '1. check target
    If targetFI.Exists And Not (PermitOverwrite) Then
        'Throw New ApplicationException("Target file already exists")
        RaiseEvent StatusChanged("Target file already exists")
    End If
    '2. check source
    Dim URI As String = GetCurrentUrl() & "/" & sourceFilename
    '3. perform copy
    Dim ftp As Net.FtpWebRequest = GetRequest(URI)
    'Set request to download a file in binary mode
    ftp.Method = Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile
    ftp.UseBinary = True
    'open request and get response stream
    Using response As FtpWebResponse = CType(ftp.GetResponse, FtpWebResponse)
        Using responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream
            'loop to read & write to file
            Using fs As FileStream = targetFI.OpenWrite
                Try
                    Dim buffer(2047) As Byte
                    Dim read As Integer = 0
                    Do
                        read = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                        fs.Write(buffer, 0, read)
                    Loop Until read = 0
                    responseStream.Close()
                    fs.Flush()
                    fs.Close()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    'catch error and delete file only partially downloaded
                    fs.Close()
                    'delete target file as it's incomplete
                    targetFI.Delete()
                    'Throw
                    RaiseEvent StatusChanged("Download was incomplete due to an error...")
                End Try
            End Using
            responseStream.Close()
        End Using
        response.Close()
    End Using
    Return True
End Function
```